# 'No module named' e sys.path.append

Tags: python, pycharm, import

Estou utilizando PyCharm para aprender Python e na hora de importar para o console um módulo de estudo ('data') que eu criei, ocorre o seguinte aviso:

```
    Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "C:\Users\raiss\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python310\lib\code.py", line 90, in runcode
    exec(code, self.locals)
  File "<input>", line 1, in <module>
  File "C:\Program Files\JetBrains\PyCharm Community Edition 2022.1.1\plugins\python-ce\helpers\pydev\_pydev_bundle\pydev_import_hook.py", line 21, in do_import
    module = self._system_import(name, *args, **kwargs)
ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'data'
```

Na internet, eu encontrei o seguite comando para resolver:

```
import sys
sys.path.append(' "local onde está o módulo" ')
```

Depois realizei o `from data import Classe` novamente e funcionou.

Entretanto, eu não entendi o que está acontecendo por trás disso, e queria uma explicação (suficientemente didática, se possível). Não queria ter esse problema sem entendê-lo, nem resolver ele sem saber o que estou fazendo.

Comment: Seria importante que você explicasse como está estruturada a pasta do seu projeto.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Se você criou um módulo, digamos `mod.py`, na mesma pasta do arquivo principal (que irá importá-lo), um `import mod` bastará. O problema é quando este módulo estiver em outro diretório.

Se o arquivo que você deseja importar estiver dentro de uma subpasta presente no mesmo diretório do seu arquivo principal, isto é, se ele for acessível sem ter que retornar a diretórios anteriores, também é fácil de importá-lo: `import subpasta.mod`. A saber, quaisquer definições/variáveis contidas dentro deste módulo deverão ser referenciadas no arquivo principal como `subpasta.mod.funcao_dentro_do_mod()`, a menos que você mude isso usando `from x import y as z`.

Por fim, você pode querer importar um módulo contido em um diretório anterior àquele que seu script roda, ou mesmo em um diretório completamente diferente. Nesse caso, você precisa pedir ao interpretador que ele busque os módulos contidos naquela pasta, porque por padrão ele só vai buscar os módulos contidos na pasta do interpretador, que contém a *standard library* e todos os módulos/bibliotecas que você instalou usando `pip install`; e na pasta (e todas subpastas) do arquivo principal que foi executado.

Daí que entra o `sys.path`. Isto na verdade é uma lista de endereços em que o interpretador vai buscar os módulos que você tenta importar, e se o módulo que você precisa não estiver em um dos endereços contidos *a priori* nesta lista, você pode dar fazer um `append` e importar depois disso.

Answer (score -3):

Basicamente, vc estava tentando acessar um recurso que não fazia parte do projeto, ao importá-lo ele passou a ser parte integrante desse projeto, logo, reconhecido pelo seu nome.
Podemos usar como exemplo quando um aluno de um curso está presente em sala mas não na chamada, embora o professor possa avaliá-lo e anotar suas presenças e ausências ele não poderá adicionar suas notas no sistema enquanto este não for cadastrado na chamada da turma (ou seja, como parte integrante dela).

Comment: oie! na verdade deixei passar esse detalhe na descrição do problema, mas antes de dar o erro eu fiz o import sim, dessa maneira: `from data import Classe` (data é o script e Classe é a classe que tava importando). 
ou seja, eu importei o recurso e mesmo com o import deu o erro :/  
só consegui fazer o import depois daquele `sys.path.append`, por isso nao entendi o que tinha de errado antes disso

Comment: Ahh, entendi. Poderia me passar a estrutura das pastas e arquivos do seu projeto?

Comment: Pq assim, o sys.psth sempre irá consultar um módulo que esteja no mesmo diretório que o arquivo que esteja executando está localizado, no entanto, se essa pasta tiver outras pastas dentro dela e vc fizer sua importação, sem o append o sys path não consegue compreender que o arquivo possa estar dentro de outras pastas dentro, ou fora, do seu diretório.
Neste link vc consegue mais informações sobre: https://linuxhint.com/sys-path-append-python/

Comment: aaah, entendi! o `sys.path.extend` não estava incluindo a pasta que está o script. ao modificar o diretório dele deu certo, nem precisou botar o `sys.path.append`, somente modificá-lo no início. obrigada!! :)